# Referencing to mysqli_connect.php Breaks PHPExcel Downloader

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I am a new developer and have recently finished coding up a simple PHP mySQL DBMS for my company. Now that I am done *getting it to work*, I want to make it secure, implementing all the security best-practices I can find on the web (Ex: Regular Expressions, having mysqli_connect.php outside web directory vs connection strings inside script, etc.) before I take it online. I have editted some personal information outside of this code and replaced it with what its job was, but inside brackets. I don't want to leave it posted online if possible.

Normally, I am able to work with my database with just a reference to mysqli_connect.php, like this:

`require_once ('..\mysqli_connect.php');`

One of the functions on my DBMS is a 'download to excel' button. It works perfectly, **but only when I have the connection directly inside of the file.** If I try write my connection like I do in the example above, the Excel file displays the following error message:

`Excel cannot open the file 'xyz.xlsx' because the file format or extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.`

When I write the connection directly inside the ExcelDownload.php, the Excel file downloads correctly. The connection string looks like this:

`$dbc = @mysqli_connect( '[myhost]', '[myusername]', '[mypassword]', '[mydatabase]')`

So again, basically, referencing the connection indirectly causes my Excel download to bug out and I don't know why. It works fine if I directly summon the connection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again, Jibreel

Here is ExcelDownload.php, by the way:

```
<?php
session_start();

//VERIFY LOGGED IN: Redirects user back to home page if they are not logged in or if they don't have the right privileges. Should be atop every page.
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{header("Location: login.php");}

//CALLS PHPEXCEL: Creates connection to PHPExcel class library, and creates new instance of PHPExcel. 
//                From there it sets the attributes for some of PHPExcel's methods, to explain how we want the spreadsheet to be designed.

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('OpenOrders');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', '[my company]');

//CONFIRMATION: If Export to Excel button is pushed, then do this
if(isset($_POST["export_Excel"]))
{


    //DANGER!! UNSECURED DATABASE CONNECTION. BAD PRACTICE. CHANGE IN NEXT VERSION!
    //GENERATE QUERY: Connects to database -- Once connected, runs select * query and saves the outcome in $result
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect( '[myhost]', '[myusername]', '[mypassword]', '[mydb]')
    OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    $sql = "[myquery]";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

    //SET HEADING VALUE: Sets the values for the top row of the spreadsheet, which will be the headings.
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C3', 'OOPONO');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D3', 'Order Status');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E3', 'Order Comments');




    //ITERATOR: If there are values inside of $result, starting at row 4, insert values for OOPONO, order status, and comments until $results is totally intereated.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {

            $rownumber = 4;

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $row1 = 'C'.$rownumber;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($row1, $row["OOPONO"]);
                $row1 = 'D'.$rownumber;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($row1, $row["Order_Status"]);
                $row1 = 'E'.$rownumber;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($row1, $row["Comments"]);


                $rownumber = $rownumber + 1;
            }                       
        }
}

//DOWNLOAD SETUP: Defines the different attributes of the Excel doc ranging from filename to extension. It also does the finishing touches of setting up the download.
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="OpenOrders.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> So again, basically, referencing the connection indirectly causes my Excel download to bug out and I don't know why. It works fine if I directly summon the connection.

No! `referencing the connection indirectly causes` an error, which results in an error message, which is sent to your display; and then the Excel output is also sent to your display, so that the error message becomes part of the Excel datastream content, and so the error message is injected into the file, resulting in a corrupted file.

Open the file in a text editor, and you should be able to see the actual error message that you are getting

Comment: I opened the file and there were only a bunch of totally random characters. I tried changing the extension to .txt but still got the same result. The result is too long to post here. Can you help me know where to go from here?



Thank you :-)

Comment: I can't help you easily..... I've told you what the problem is, but I don't have access to your logs, your files, etc to point you to an actual line

Comment: Ok, I will do my best then and try to solve it myself. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: It's almost certainly going to be a scope issue with your connection, but difficult to say more than that